# How to use 1 configuration for all aliases of an SCDF task in a flow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have an **SCDF composite task flow** with multiple tasks. At the end of the flow OR when any task in the flow fails, a final "analyzer" task must be launched to create and send a report about the flow processing.

The composite task looks like this:

```
task1 'FAILED' -> analyzer &&
task2 'FAILED' -> analyzer &&
task3 '*'      -> analyzer
```

When I launch this task flow, I get the following error message because the **task `analyzer` is used multiple times**:

```
duplicate app name. Use a label to ensure uniqueness
```

To prevent this, I can **alias the `analyzer` task** for every use.
Then I got

```
task1 'FAILED' -> task1-analyzer:analyzer &&
task2 'FAILED' -> task2-analyzer:analyzer &&
task3 '*'      -> task3-analyzer:analyzer
```

This works fine, BUT with this definition my `analyzer` task fails because it is **missing its configuration properties**.

It seems that now I need to **configure each alias of the `analyzer` task individually**. Even when the configuration is the same for all of them.

For example

```
deployer.my-composite.analyzer.kubernetes...
```

becomes

```
deployer.my-composite.task1-analyzer.kubernetes...
deployer.my-composite.task2-analyzer.kubernetes...
deployer.my-composite.task3-analyzer.kubernetes...
```

**Is it possible to configure all aliases of a task with just one configuration?** I have flows with about 10 processing tasks and it is quite annoying to repeat the same properties 10 times.

Or is there a **simpler way to express the conditional flow** so that I don't need 10 aliases of my analyzer task?